# Replacing string text with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in javascript/jQuery a string whose content is set via a settings field by the user. The setting invites users to use predefined shortcodes like: [firstname] and [email]. So the content of the javascript string may be: 
"Hi [firstname], thanks for submitting the form! We sent a confirmation email to [email]. Thanks"

How do I in javascript/jQuery replace these shortcodes with javascript variables so it ends up being something like:

```
var userSetting = 'Hi ' + firstname + ', thanks for submitting the form! We sent a confirmation email to ' + email + '. Thanks';
```

Thanks for your help! I don't believe this is a duplicate because I am not trying to do a simple string replacement, I am trying to replace a string with a predefined variable.

Comment: Are you trying to replace `[`, `]` characters? Or replace string `"[email]"` with variable `email`?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is another scenario. Instead of a string as a replacement value, he wants to replace it with a variable

Comment: Hi guest271314, I am trying to replace "[email]" with a variable called email. Thanks